# What was Singapore's population in 1290-1396, 1511-1699?

Tags: population, singapore

Michael Barr [calls](https://books.google.com/books?id=KxKEDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT28) 1290-1396 and 1511-1699 Singapore's first and second periods of prosperity.

Are there any estimates of Singapore's population during these two periods? (Even rough orders of magnitude would be helpful.)

Answer (score 3):

McEvedy and Jones's [Atlas of World Population History](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/624253.Atlas_of_World_Population_History) (no longer in print, but if you can find a copy, buy it) has a separate call-out for the population of "Malaysia and Singapore". Obviously, that's not Singapore alone, but it could certainly be used as a ceiling.

It shows that entire area having about 300,000 souls around 1300, and steadily climbing up to about 600,000 by 1700.

A report from a Chinese traveler [in 1330](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Singapore#Ancient_Singapore) was that there were *two* settlements on the island, so it wasn't a unified urban unit at the time. If you can find a version of [his writings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daoyi_Zhil%C3%BCe) in a language you can read, its possible he might have provided a better idea of the rough size of those settlements.

Comment: "Malaysia and Singapore" is very different from Singapore. When the British colonized Singapore in 1819, there were only a few 100 or at most about 1000 persons in Singapore.

Comment: @user103496 - I quoted that to indicate that this was the book's wording, not mine. Mr. McEvedy sadly passed almost 2 decades ago, so if you don't like how he categorized things, I'm afraid there isn't much that can be done about it at this remove. Perhaps when we all meet up in that big Indiana Jones dive bar in the sky, we can have a good conversation with him about it.